# Left button -> Send to...(no option to send the file as an attachment using evolution)

Tags: 11.04, evolution

Ubuntu 11.04 Beta 2: Selecting a file and clicking Left button (on the mouse) and then selecting "Send to"...(no option to send the file as an attachment on evolution) 
On the previous version this was working, why not now?

Answer (score 2):

> Please note Javier's comment:
>   "There is now (July 6th, 2011) an update in propossed that solves this issue"
>   <sup>(~ stefano)</sup>

[Ubuntuforum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1722178) reports that this helps:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libebook-1.2.so.10 /usr/lib/libebook-1.2.so.9
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libedataserver-1.2.so.14 /usr/lib/libedataserver-1.2.so.13
```

Comment: It worked for me and other people are reporting the same in the bug.

Comment: There is now (July 6th, 2011) an update in propossed that solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Log a bug. Natty is NOT ready and NOT stable. If you need an OS which is stable then use Lucid or Maverick. If you are happy to stomach bugs and feature holes and want to log bugs to get Natty ready for release then use Natty.

Comment: I've been unable to see it reported so I opened a new bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-sendto/+bug/765847